# needed alert box functionality in SFML 2.0

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

I am making a **"TIC TAC TOE"** game using **SFML 2.0** and Microsoft visual studio - 2010 express edition . I'm in need of alert box functionality .

I thought of making an alert Window using sf::RenderWindow and hide it and then display it when and where required as alert box . But that is not effective .

Need help

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, currently there is no functionality to add pop up window in win32 console application using xfml. so you can use win32 project and there you will find MessageBoxA() to perform the same, which is present in window.h file.